# Появляется ошибка Undefined property: Route::$routes

Tags: php, ооп, маршрутизация

Подключаю файлы:

```
<?php
    require_once 'app/core/routeconfig.php';
    require_once 'app/core/route.php';

    $route = new Route;
    $route -> Run();
?>
```

Вот сам файл Route:

```
class Route{

    public $any = '([A-Za-z]+)';
    private $num = '([0-9]+)';
    public $controller;
    public $action;
    public $params = array();
    public $route;

    function getUrl(){

        return rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

    }

    function getRoute(){
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->routes as $route){

            $pattern = $route['pattern'];
            $pattern = str_replace(':any', $this->any, $pattern);
            $pattern = str_replace(':num', $this->num, $pattern);

            //get uri
            $uri = $this->getUrl();

            if(preg_match('#^'.$pattern.'$#', $uri)){

                $this->controller = $route['path']['controller'];
                $this->action = $route['path']['action'];
                if(!empty($route[$i]['path']['params'])){
                    foreach ($route[$i]['path']['params'] as $param => $value) {

                        $params = array($param => $value);
                    }
                }

                break;

            } $i++;
        }
        return array($this->controller, $this->action);
    }

    public function Run(){
        $this->route = $this->getRoute();
        $controller = $this->route[0];
        $action_name = 'Action_'.$this->route[1];
        $controller_name = $this->connectionFile($controller);

        $controller = new $controller_name;
        $controller -> $action_name(); 
    }

    function connectionFile($controller){

        $this->controller = $controller;

        $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller;
        $controller_file = strtolower($controller_name).'.php';
        $model_name = 'Model_'.$controller;
        $model_file = strtolower($model_name).'.php';

        if(file_exists('app/controllers/'.$controller_file)){
            include 'app/controllers/'.$controller_file;
        }else{

        }

        if(file_exists('app/models/'.$model_file)){
            include 'app/models/'.$model_file;
        }

        return $controller_name;
}

}
```

А вот файл routeconfig

```
<?php

$routes = array(

    array(
        'pattern' => '/show/me/fully',
        'path' => 
            array(
                'controller' => 'Account',
                'action' => 'index',
                'params' => array()
            )
        )
    )

?>
```

Получается что роут не видит переменную с массивом, помогите новичку)

Comment: Вам скорее всего тогда надо передать ваш `$routes` в конструктор класса `new Route($routes)`.... а в конструкторе, если я правильно понимаю надо переменную `$routes` добавить... и в конструкторе получится `$this->routes = $routes;` ...... хотя конечно поля routes и route в классе как-то смотреться странно будут

Comment: Я это сделал, но все равно не видно массив этот(

Comment: ну ка покажите. только не тут, а например в ideone.com

Comment: Заработало, спасибо за помощь, добавил конструктор и все заработало, просто путаюсь пока с $this->

Comment: https://ideone.com/r6LEC8   ..... еще я тут смотрю `$route` не используется больше нигде, поэтому её как поле из класса можно выкинуть (если не используется больше нигде), а в `Run` можно локальной переменной заменить `$route = $this->getRoute();
        $controller = $route[0];
        $action_name = 'Action_'.$route[1]; .....`

Comment: Да, действительно, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь пройтись по свойству объекта `routes`, которого нет (`foreach ($this->routes as $route){`). Есть совершенно независимая переменная `$routes`.
В `foreach` передавайте `$routes`.

**UPDATE**:

Можно добавить в метод доступ к глобальной переменной через ключевое слово `global`:

```
global $routes;
foreach ($routes as $route){
```

---

Но правильнее всего передать в конструктор зависимые данные:

1. Добавить свойство для класса:

   ```
   protected $_routes;
   ```
2. Прописать конструктор:

   ```
   public function __construct($data){
     $this->_routes = (array) $data;
   }
   ```
3. Вызывать так:

   ```
   foreach ($this->_routes as $route){
   ```

Comment: Подскажите как это сделать пожалуйста)

Comment: Я убрал ключевое слово this, оставил просто $routes, но это не помогло(

Comment: @Igor, обновил ответ.

Comment: ключевое слово globals глобальным переменную нe делает в классах.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan 1) Не `globals`, а `global`. 2) Да ладно: http://ideone.com/F8Pgct Всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
$route = new Route;
$route->route = $routes;
$route -> Run();
```

Можно передать `$routes` классу `Route` двумя путями.

1.Через конструктор

```
class Route{

    public $any = '([A-Za-z]+)';
    private $num = '([0-9]+)';
    public $controller;
    public $action;
    public $params = array();
    private $route;

    public function __construct($route){
        $this->route = $route;
    }
    ......
    ......
}

$route = new Route($routes);
```

что я не советую

2.создать новый метод - setter, где его и передавать

```
class Route{

public $any = '([A-Za-z]+)';
private $num = '([0-9]+)';
public $controller;
public $action;
public $params = array();
private $route;

public function setRoute($route){
    $this->route = $route;
}
......
......
}
```

Код клиента класса:

```
<?php
    require_once 'app/core/routeconfig.php';
    require_once 'app/core/route.php';


$routes = array(

    array(
        'pattern' => '/show/me/fully',
        'path' => 
            array(
                'controller' => 'Account',
                'action' => 'index',
                'params' => array()
            )
        )
    );
    $route = new Route;
    $route->setRoute($routes);
    $route -> Run();
?>
```

Comment: Я сделал первым способом, а почему вы это не советуете?
Все же работает)

Comment: Называется хорошим тоном обращаться к приватным свойствам через сеттер и геттер.